# Using share sheet to directly send a content to my chat app contact

Tags: android, android-intent

In my messaging app i want to directly send a content to my app contact. like attached screenshot showing whatsapp contacts, i want to show contacts from my chat app

[image]

Answer (score 0):

found that we can use direct share https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-direct-share#8